# WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever webXmlInputStream missing in spring security 4.2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, migration, web.xml

In Spring Security 2.0.7, I am configure the `WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever` as follow:

```
<bean id="mappableRolesRetriever" 
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever">
    <property name="webXmlInputStream">
        <bean factory-bean="webXmlResource" factory-method="getInputStream"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webXmlResource" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource">
    <constructor-arg ref="servletContext"/>
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean"/>
```

However, when come to spring security 4.2.0, the `webXmlInputStream` property no longer exist in `WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever`. I go to check the source code in `WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever`, the `afterPropertiesSet()` method and I saw it doing something like retrieving data from `/WEB-INF/web.xml` like what I set in Spring security 2.

```
Resource webXml = resourceLoader.getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        Document doc = getDocument(webXml.getInputStream());
```

Does this means that I no longer need to do this configuration in Spring security 4?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @dur , yes, I tried it, and I am able to start my web. I believe that it is work. However, I am hitting `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext` error. I am still checking is it related.